# How to filter a pandas dataframe by cells that DO NOT contain a substring?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a dataframe to find rows which do not contain the string 'site'.

I know how to filter for rows which do contain 'site' but have not been able to get the reverse working. Here is what I have so far:

```
def rbs(): #removes blocked sites
    frame = fill_rate()
    mask = frame[frame['Media'].str.contains('Site')==True]
    frame = (frame != mask)
    return frame
```

But this returns an error, of course.

Comment: My intuition would be to create a new column and assign a value based on either containing or not containing the string 'site' but I couldn't figure out how to get that to work on a row by row basis..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just do `frame[~frame['Media'].str.contains('Site')]`

The `~` negates the boolean condition

So your method becomes:

```
def rbs(): #removes blocked sites
    frame = fill_rate()
    return frame[~frame['Media'].str.contains('Site')]
```

**EDIT**

it looks like you have `NaN` values judging by your errors so you have to filter these out first so your method becomes:

```
def rbs(): #removes blocked sites
    frame = fill_rate()
    frame = frame[frame['Media'].notnull()]
    return frame[~frame['Media'].str.contains('Site')]
```

the `notnull` will filter out the missing values

Comment: I get an error saying "bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'"

Comment: Do you have `NaN` values? could you try `frame[~frame['Media'].dropna().str.contains('Site')]`, also you'd have to post raw input data or your actual data in order for me to reproduce your error

Comment: After trying yu=our suggestion EdChum, there is now an "Unalignable boolean Series key provided" error displaying.

Comment: I think you have `NaN` values you could drop these prior to the filter so after the `frame = fill_rate()` line do `frame = frame[frame['Media'].notnull()]` could you try that

Comment: Note, if you want to maintain the NaN values, you could use:

frame = fill_rate()
frame[~frame['Media'].str.contains('Site', na=False)]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `== False` instead of `~`

Your example:
`frame[frame['Media'].str.contains('Site') == False]`